# How to make it so ajax does not run when page loads, but only when submit on a form is pushed?

Tags: html, ajax, forms

I have a form that i want an administrator to fill out, then click submit and have the ajax run. At the moment this works, however, it also runs as soon as the page is loaded, something I do not want to happen. The code is as follows:

```
<script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">        </script>
<script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function() {


$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajaxtest.php",
  async:false,
  data: { product_id: "1" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});

});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="frmAJAX" action="" method="POST" >
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>"/>
<p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $product_id; ?></p>
<label name="product_sku" type="text">Item SKU</label>
<input type="text"  value="<?=$product_sku?>" name="product_sku"/><br />
<label name="product_name" type="text">Item</label>
<input type="text" value="<?=$product_name?>"  name="product_name"/><br />


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I would like to do is keep the ajax from running when the page loads, but let it run when the submit button is used. Any suggestions?

Comment: What you describe is exactly what your code already does: http://jsfiddle.net/zS2FK/

Comment: The way this code is set up, it should only run when the form submit event happens.  Is there anything in the page that could be causing the form to be submitted automatically?

Comment: No that is the only code on the page, and its not calling anything else.

Comment: concur, this works exactly as you wish. Tip: instead of hardcoding the form's submit URL in the JS, why not put into the `action` attribute of the `<form>` itself and read that attribute in your JS? This way the form will work fine with and without JS

Comment: Ah I hardcoded it so that way i could test it out without seeing if the form was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to change the submit button to type="button" and then change the form submit function to the click event of this button. This change in the form submit logic might help fix the problem or uncover what the problem was.
example:

```
$('#[buttonid]').click(function(){
    //put ajax function here
});
```

Comment: Hmm i am not quite sure how to do that, i am not very familiar with ajax and jquery. Do you have an example of this?

Comment: are you looking to post the form as well? if so after the AJAX call you can add $('#[formID]').submit();

Answer (score 0):

You may need `return false` at the end of the AJAX call. Also I'd personally, try @TheAmazingJason's way.

Answer (score 0):

you could try by giving id to select form rather than by tag like

```
$("#frmAJAX").submit(function() {
```